# ITempDataProvider in MVC 6 to use cookies for tempdata

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core-mvc

I'm migrating a site over to use MVC 6.  Currently I have tempdata store in cookies, but I can't find the set up of how to do this in the new MVC framework.

Comment: I'm having the same problem.  Did you resolve this?

Comment: Found it, answer is below.  As noted, the deleting of the cookie is a bit wonky and I'm not sure if it is a beta issue or something else.  I wanted to share my success on this issue with you, so if you solve the cookie issue, please let us know.

Comment: A new `CookieTempDataProvider` has just been introduced as part of [ASP.Net Core 1.1](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/webdev/2016/11/16/announcing-asp-net-core-1-1/)

Answer (score 0):

First, implement your ITempDataProvider.  I did it this way, using JSON.Net.

```
public class CookieTempDataProvider : ITempDataProvider
{
    readonly string CookieKey = "_tempdata";

    public IDictionary<string,object> LoadTempData(HttpContext context)
    {
        var cookieValue = context.Request.Cookies[this.CookieKey];
        if(string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(cookieValue))
        {
            return new Dictionary<string, object>();
        }

        var decoded = Convert.FromBase64String(cookieValue);
        var jsonAsString = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(decoded);            
        var dictionary = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<IDictionary<string,object>>(jsonAsString, new JsonSerializerSettings { TypeNameHandling = TypeNameHandling.All, TypeNameAssemblyFormat = FormatterAssemblyStyle.Full });

        // The cookie really should be deleted when the SaveTempData() method is called with an empty dictionary
        // but that does not seem to be working for some reason.  Added this delete for now (maybe this is a beta issue)
        // TODO: Revisit at next release
        context.Response.Cookies.Delete(this.CookieKey);

        return dictionary;
    }

    public void SaveTempData(HttpContext context, IDictionary<string,object> values)
    {
        if (values == null || values.Count == 0)
        {
            context.Response.OnStarting(() => Task.Run(() =>
            {
                context.Response.Cookies.Delete(this.CookieKey);
            }));

            return;
        }

        var jsonAsString = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(values, new JsonSerializerSettings { TypeNameHandling = TypeNameHandling.All, TypeNameAssemblyFormat = FormatterAssemblyStyle.Full });
        var bytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(jsonAsString);
        var encoded = Convert.ToBase64String(bytes);

        context.Response.Cookies.Append(this.CookieKey, encoded);
    }        
}
```

Next, in Startup.cs, where services are wired up, replace the default ITempDataProvider with your custom version, like so:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    // Replace Temp Data Provider
    var existing = services.FirstOrDefault(x => x.ServiceType == typeof(ITempDataProvider));
    services.Remove(existing);
    services.AddSingleton<ITempDataProvider, CookieTempDataProvider>();
}
```

**EDIT**

Since RC2 the original answer doesn't work any longer due to what seems like timing changes in the MVC request lifecycle...you'll receive an error about not being able to modify headers.  I've updated the SaveTempData() method above to account for this.

Answer (score 0):

I also had this need, so I've implemented a cookie-based *TempData* provider for ASP.NET Core MVC and published it on NuGet. It is available [here](https://github.com/luisgoncalves/aspnetcore-cookietempdata).

Answer (score -1):

If you think about TempData class for storing data for next request, there is some changes in MVC 6. You need to add additional package and configure it. Here are steps:

1. Remove "dnxcore50" from frameworks section in [project.json]. Session hasn't implementd yet in dnxcore50.
2. In the [project.json] add:

   ```
   "Microsoft.AspNet.Session": "1.0.0-rc1-final"
   ```
3. Enable Caching and Session in class **Startup.cs**, method **ConfigureServices**, by adding next lines **after** services.AddMvc():

   ```
   services.AddCaching();
   services.AddSession();
   ```
4. Cinfigure it on class **Startup.cs**, method **Configure**, adding next line **before** app.UseMvc(...):

   ```
   app.UseSession();
   ```

And that's it. But remember, you can store only primitive or serializable data types. If you need to store user defined data type, you need to serialized it. For that purpose we use "Newtonsoft.Json" lib. Here is example:

```
string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(myObject);
TempData["myKey"] = json;
```

Comment: Thanks, but I'm looking at keeping the temp data in cookies